# Windows Server Edition and Hotfix Compatibility

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, windows

I am fairly new to Windows, coming from a Linux/Apache background so I apologize up front.

I am trying to apply [this ASP.NET hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600100) that updates browser definitions to include IE 10.

I incorrectly tried to install the wrong hotfix file: Windows6.1-KB2600100-x64 but then tried with the correct file (Windows6.0-KB2600100-x64) and got the same error:

[image]

[image]

My Operating System is **Windows Server Std (2008) SP1**

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.0.6001]
Copyright (c) 2006 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>wmic OS get OperatingSystemSKU
7


>wmic OS get OSArchitecture
64-bit
```

[image]

According to the hotfix prereqs, these OS versions are supported:

**Windows XP**

**Windows Server 2003**

**Windows Vista**

**Windows Server 2008**

**Windows 7 SP1**

**Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1**

The only other prereq was .NET Framework 2.0 SP2 or of the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 is installed.
What could be the issue? When I look at the browser definition list, I do not see IE 10 so I don't think the hotfix was ever applied now or in the past

I appreciate any experience or suggestions with this

Thanks

Comment: Also give us the exact file name of the hotfix and your exact processor architecture. There will be several different patches for 32 bit, 64 bit, Itaniums...

Comment: Do you definitely not have the hotfix already installed? Generally if a hotfix says it's not applicable, that's that..!

Comment: when i look in the browser definitions, IE10 is not there so i don't think the hotfix was applied

Comment: At this point I think I would be yelling at Microsoft.

Comment: @Slinky Check in Add / Remove Programs (You'll need to click "Show Updates"). Also did you definitely download the right architecture (I.e., x86 or x64)?

Comment: @Dan I checked in "Installed Updates". I searched by KB number and also by ASP.NET, .NET. Nothing came up. The file looks right for this OS: 1-KB2600100-x64

Comment: Did you check a few of the files mentioned in the kb article and verify whether your existing versions are older or newer?  I'm pretty sure it will give you that error as well if your existing file versions are newer than the ones in the KB article list.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the wrong hotfix - you've downloaded the one for Server 2008 R2 / Windows 7.

Yours should be called Windows6.0-KB2600100-x64.msu

This is the download link:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I voted up your answer but it did not solve the problem; i updated my question accordingly